# Python 2.7 file read error

Tags: python-2.7

I am struggling with file access - I have my python 2.7 here: 
`C:\Python27`

I created a txt file *data.txt*

and I am trying to get the shell to read and print values from it. Location of *data.txt* is in the same folder (C:\Python27\data.txt)

Every time I got the same error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/FileReader.py", line 1, in <module>
infile = open('data.txt', 'r')  # Open the file for reading.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enter the full filename *data.txt* instead of data only:

`infile = open('data.txt', 'r')`

Comment: My mistake. I have full file name in my code data.txt as a name of the file I try to access.

Comment: Please treat this topic as closed.

Comment: @kalenji - that's something you can easily do yourself. If you found a solution, ad an answer to your own question and mark it accepted. This will make it visible as solved, and provides possible future users some help